# How to use Cherrypy to return error page with different error message?

Tags: python, html, cherrypy

I am new to Python **`Cherrypy`**. I want to display an error page using totally the same html file with only change on the error message (string).

I only know how to display a webpage without parameters (i.e.**`return file('error.html')`**). But how can I display the **`error.html`** with a different error message (work as a parameter)?

Comment: You may (1) use some template engine (like `jinja2`) to interpolate your html templates or (2) set appropriate `error_page` in config. See example: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/tutorial/tut10_http_errors.py

Comment: @webKnjaZ Thanks for your advice~  I use jinja2 and it works now~

Comment: Still keep in mind, that in this case you return HTTP code 200 OK, whereas it should be 404. So consider setting response code manually to conform standards.